# Adding Cache Mongodb Panache Quarkus Reactive

Tags: mongodb, caching, quarkus, quarkus-panache, quarkus-reactive

im trying to speed up my mongodb panache query's using quarkus and reactive, im trying to use cache and get a better pagination but cant make it work, this are my java class:

```
@ApplicationScoped
@RegisterForReflection
public class BrandRepository implements ReactivePanacheMongoRepositoryBase<Brands, Integer> {

  public ReactivePanacheQuery<Brands> listBrands() {
    return Brands.findAll(Sort.by("name").ascending());
  }
}

@Path("/brand/")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@RegisterForReflection
public class brand {
  private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(brand.class);

  @Inject BrandRepository br;

  @GET
  public Uni<Response> list(
      @DefaultValue("0") @QueryParam("page") Integer page,
      @DefaultValue("10") @QueryParam("page_size") Integer page_size) {
    Pagination pagination = new Pagination();
    if (page != null && page >= 1) {
      pagination.setPage(page);
      page--;
    } else {
      page = 0;
      pagination.setPage(1);
    }
    if (page_size == null || page_size <= 0) {
      page_size = 10;
    }
    pagination.setPageSize(page_size);
    return br.listBrands()
        .page(Page.of(page, page_size))
        .list()
        .map(
            b -> {
              pagination.setTotalCount(b.size());
              LOG.info("listBrands");
              return Response.ok(
                      new BrandResponseList(new Metadata("success", 200, "ok"), b, pagination))
                  .build();
            });
  }
}
```

The other trouble im having is to count the total of br.listBrands() and no the total after paginating.

Thank You For The Help

Comment: It's not clear from your question what the problem is. Please make the description clearer.

Comment: Know if there is a way to make the mongo panache query quicker, using cache or another thing.

Answer (score 0):

For cache, did you try to use `@CacheResult`?

Here we have a guide explaining how to use https://quarkus.io/guides/cache